# Unable to install GitHub for Windows

Tags: windows-8.1, github-for-windows

I'm trying to install github for windows when I received this error:

```
Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.
```

The error log produced this:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [8/22/2014 12:51:27 AM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [8/22/2014 12:51:28 AM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionState.Validate()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

According to https://status.github.com/messages ,  there are no issues currently with the servers.
I am on a personal computer so there shouldn't be any issues with the connection. I tried downloading the application directly from  http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application , but the result was the same.

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro x64.

---

Edit 1: Currently I'm working around being unable to install GitHub for Windows by first installing it on another system, then taking the newly installed files from %appdata%\Local\Apps\2.0, and moving them to the system that is having trouble installing. (The full directory is %appdata%\Local\Apps\2.0\EWG9HYRR.BKG\2XKOJCRD.XRD\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.0002_f44dcb2e9d4cde94).

One of the major caveats of this workaround is that on the problem system, GitHub for Windows will report "This isn't a networked deployed app." and therefor not automatically update.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After contacting support, they emailed me and helped me work through the problem preventing GitHub for windows from installing.

This is a problem with the ClickOnce Application Cache.

> 1. Before proceeding make sure that you have connectivity.
> 2. Sometimes Firewall may be blocking this ***.application**
> 3. So turn off you firewall for *private* and *public* profile and then retry.
> 4. If the issue persists, you can use the process specified below.

1. Hold down the `Windows` key and type `R`.
2. Type in `rundll32 %SystemRoot%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache` in the run dialog and hit `Enter`.

Then try installing the application.

If that doesn't work, there's a more manual approach to ensuring the cache is cleared - you can delete the ClickOnce Application folder directly. On `Windows Vista` or higher, this will be the `%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0` directory. Simply delete the `%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0` directory and restart github for windows.

If nothing seems to happen after running the installer, you may need to restart Windows, or `explorer.exe` (if using the .msi installer, the app may be in: `%LocalAppData%\GitHubDesktop`)

Comment: I needed to delete the directory and I'm on 8.1 as well.

Comment: Windows 10 firewall was the problem on my machine, had to temporarily disable it for the Github installation.

Comment: Your solution running rundll32 %SystemRoot%\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache only fixed my problem immediately on Windows 10 new install.

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue as well installing github on Windows 8 x64, I tried all suggestions above related to removing the 2.0 directory but with no luck. Later I found a blog saying that one guy solved this issue by downloading the installer using Internet Explorer (weird right?) Surprisingly for me, it worked! Hre is the link https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application So I recommend you to do the same, at least IE is worth for something :)

Best

Comment: Sadly this is the only way I could get the install/download to work.

Comment: this worked on Win7 for me. So crazy that Github can't seem to figure this out after 2 and a half years

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 64-bit also.

Answer (score 12):

For Windows 8.1 64-Bit,

1. Go to file Explorer (*Shortcut:* windows key + E).
2. Paste this " **%LocalAppData%\Apps**" (without inverted commas) in you file explorer panel (which displays your current location in file explorer.
3. Press Enter key.
4. Delete the folder named 2.0 .

In my case, this worked without a glitch. I Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

It worked fine for me. Really deleting the directory worked fine.

If you have problems locating the directory copy directly %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0 on the explorer window. Delete every folder you find there and it will work.

Great response as it was really annoying for me.

Comment: I needed to delete the directory and I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: In my case the above solution does not work....and every time I go to install github the folders I delete...are created again

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today on Windows 10 so the issue is still there. The solution provided by @JoeC above solved my issue. The error I received was:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.10586.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1063.1 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2016-02-01 06:29:55] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2016-02-01 06:29:56] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - The referenced assembly is not installed on your system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B3)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.GetAssemblyInformation(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.Store.GetAssemblyManifest(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionIdentity DefinitionIdentity)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetAssemblyManifest(DefinitionIdentity asmId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(DefinitionIdentity subId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionStateInternal(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see answers here and understand that i did dumb thing.
I just made small script that copied all tmp files during installation.

Made small Windows `copygithub.cmd` file:

```
:loop

xcopy  C:\Users\Stall\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment C:\github /y /h /i /s

goto loop
```

Its just a copy in a `loop`. Start it before install github. And close after you receive an error.

Once it get a fail, all files are erased. So i didn't want to miss any file. This copy is in infinity loop. So you should stop it after you got error.

It does not solve issue, but i received working github.
That's what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we had was that a third-party security application that controlled our corporate firewall on each device was blocking ClickOnce from accessing dfshim.dll over WiFi, so one potential solution for us was to have our inspectors start the .NET application while connected via ethernet and then after the app was booted up they could go out and perform their inspections.