# Why github installation gets stuck even when internet is working?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am trying to install GitHub on my Windows 8 system. I downloaded it from github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com . Every time installation stops and I get the error message that your internet connection is not working but in actual that is not the case, all other websites open very well. Can someone recommend some solution to this? Is there any other kind of package available which I can download first and then install without requiring internet connection? Responses will be very helpful. The error log is :

PLATFORM VERSION INFO

```
Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
```

SOURCES

```
Deployment url          : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application
                    Server      : AmazonS3
Application url         : http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application%20Files/GitHub_3_3_3_0/GitHub.exe.manifest
                    Server      : AmazonS3
```

IDENTITIES

```
Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=3.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86
Application Identity        : GitHub.exe, Version=3.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86, type=win32
```

APPLICATION SUMMARY

```
* Installable application.
* Trust url parameter is set.
```

ERROR SUMMARY

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_3_3_3_0/PortableGit.7z.deploy did not succeed.
    + Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    + An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY

```
No transaction error was detected.
```

WARNINGS

```
There were no warnings during this operation.
```

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS

```
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:07 AM] : Activation of http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application has started.
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:15 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:15 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:22 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:34 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
* [01-Dec-16 11:18:34 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
```

ERROR DETAILS

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [01-Dec-16 11:27:28 AM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
    - Downloading http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/Application Files/GitHub_3_3_3_0/PortableGit.7z.deploy did not succeed.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.IO.IOException
    - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
    - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    - Source: System
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS

```
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: I have no idea, but perhaps try running the installer as an administrator

Comment: Hi, I tried that way also, but still same problem is there.

Comment: Would one of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/q/25439865/6309 help?

Comment: Thanks for response, but the errors in my error log are different. I have now added those errors too. You can have a look upon.

Comment: Did you try all the solutions in the post @VonC linked?

Comment: I switched to another network and that worked for me.

Comment: Have the same issue. Really frustrating.